# Laravel Octane with roundrunner not recognizing .php file

Tags: php, laravel, octane

i am trying to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php with php artisan octane:start.
but when i hit this url it shows index.php code screenshot is attached
[it should be redirect on landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg13d.png)

i am expecting it to be landing page instead of code.here is my rr.yaml code

`version: 3
http:
address: 127.0.0.1:8000 # The address where RoadRunner will listen for incoming HTTP requests
workers:
command: "/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php" # Replace with the actual path to your PHP binary (e.g., /usr/bin/php or the path to your MAMP PHP binary)
pool:
numWorkers: 4 # The number of worker processes to spawn
maxJobs: 64 # The maximum number of jobs each worker can handle before being recycled

## relay:

## dsn: "unix:///path/to/your/roadrunner.sock" # Replace with the actual path to the Unix socket (e.g., /tmp/roadrunner.sock)

```
static:
    dir: "/Users/apple/Sites/a-counting/public" # Replace with the path to the public directory of your Laravel project
    forbid: [".php"] # Prevent access to PHP files directly

# Define custom handlers if needed
handlers:
  - {method: GET, path: /index, handler: \App\Http\Handlers\CustomHandler::handle}

# Enable health checks for RoadRunner
#health:
#  address: ":9191"

# Set the maximum request duration (optional)
#maxRequestDuration: 60s

# Set the maximum request body size (optional)
#maxRequestBodySize: "16M"

# Set the maximum response body size (optional)
#maxResponseBodySize: "64M"

# Configure GRPC server (optional)
#grpc:
#  listen: "tcp://127.0.0.1:6000"
#  proto: "/path/to/your/grpc/proto/file.proto"
#  services:
#    - \My\GRPC\Service::class

# Configure metrics server (optional)
#metrics:
#  address: ":8085"
#  collect: ["runtime", "http"]
```

`